# Xpath unexpected backslash problems

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, backslash

I'm trying to extract some json files from HTML using scrapy, I have two problems and they are conflicting each other.

One of them is the **brandName** problem, which appears on this website: http://us.asos.com/barneys-originals/barneys-faux-leather-biker-jacket/prd/7949149?clr=black&SearchQuery=barneys+faux+biker&pgesize=9&pge=0&totalstyles=9&gridsize=3&gridrow=1&gridcolumn=1

Part of the HTML element that contains the json file looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   require(['Pages/FullProduct'], function (view) {
      view('{"id":7949149,
             "name":"Barneys Faux Leather Biker Jacket",
             "brandName":"Barney\'s Originals"
      }');
   });
</script>
```

The other one is the **size** problem, which appears on this website:
http://us.asos.com/asos/asos-3-pack-smart-slim-belt-in-faux-leather-save/prd/7098512?clr=multi&cid=21809

Part of the HTML element that contains the json file looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   require(['Pages/FullProduct'], function (view {
      view('{"id":7098512,
             "name":"ASOS 3 Pack Smart Slim Belt In Faux Leather SAVE",
             "brandName":"ASOS"
             "variants": [{
                "variantId": 7098598,
                "size": "S/M - W79-86cm",
                "sizeId": 3810,
                "colour": "Multi",
                "colourCode": "MU1",
                "isPrimary": true,
                "sizeOrder": 2
             }, {
                "variantId": 7098522,
                "size": "L/XXL - 36\\" - 40\\ " (91-102cm)",
                "sizeId": 7589,
                "colour": "Multi",
                "colourCode": "MU1",
                "isPrimary": true,
                "sizeOrder": 5}]');
             }]
      }');
   });
</script>
```

I used this method, which works well except for the text that contains "\":

```
response.xpath('//script[contains(., "Pages/FullProduct")]/text()').re_first("view\('(\{.*\})',")
```

I ran the code above and the I got text with unexpected backslashes. The xpath method adds two extra "\"s to the text where it supposed to be only one "\". It gives me error loading the json file.

For the brandName problem:

`"Barney\'s Originals"` becomes `"Barney\\\'s Originals"`.

For the size problem:

`"L/XXL - 36\\" - 40\\ " (91-102cm)"` becomes `"L/XXL - 36\\\\" - 40\\\\ " (91-102cm)"`

Then I tried erasing the extra two backslashes using the `replace("\\", "")` method:

```
response.xpath('//script[contains(., "Pages/FullProduct")]/text()').re_first("view\('(\{.*\})',").replace("\\\\", "")
```

After doing the above, the brandName problem is fixed, however the size problem becomes:

`"L/XXL - 36" - 40" (91-102cm)"`

It gives me error when loading the json file again, because it consider the first two "s a set and the second two "s a set. And I notice the original html won't pass the json validator either because it doesn't recognize the "\\".

Then I tried `replace("\\\\", "\")` for the size problem:

```
response.xpath('//script[contains(., "Pages/FullProduct")]/text()').re_first("view\('(\{.*\})',").replace("\\\\", "\")
```

But I got this error:

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

My question is: How can I solve these two conflicting problems at a same time, and getting text with only one backslash before any quote mark?

My desired result would be:

**"Barney\'s Originals"** for the brandName.

**"L/XXL - 36\" - 40\ " (91-102cm)"** for the size.

Comment: Which package are you using for xpath?  Also, what is the `re_first` method you are calling?

Comment: @James he mentioned `scrapy` at the beginning but didn't include it in the tags. It is like using a `lxml` wrapper.

Comment: Is there actually a space between the backslashes and the double quote in `size` in the second sample?

Comment: It’s probably not actually adding anything. Try running it through `json.loads` twice. `json.loads(json.loads('"%s"' % (the_regex_match,)))`

Comment: @eLRuLL Thank you all for replying. But my desired result is "Barney\'s Originals" and "L/XXL - 36\" - 40\ " (91-102cm)", because having only one "\" before any quote mark will not give me error when Ioading json file.

Comment: Actually the answer below does solve both the problems. I think it's the online json validator that confuses me, the 36\\" and 40\\" didn't passed the json validator, but in json.loads it actually did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below works fine for me in second case

```
>>> data = response.xpath('//script[contains(., "Pages/FullProduct")]/text()').re_first("view\('(\{.*\})',")
>>>
>>> data_json = json.loads(re.sub(r'[\\]+"', r'\"', data))
>>> data_json["variants"]
[{'variantId': 7098523, 'size': 'XXS/XS - W66-76cm', 'sizeId': 7588, 'colour': 'Multi', 'colourCode': 'MU1', 'isPrimary': True, 'sizeOrder': 1}, {'variantId': 7098598, 'size': 'S/M - W79-86cm', 'sizeId': 3810, 'colour': 'Multi', 'colourCode': 'MU1', 'isPrimary': True, 'sizeOrder': 2}, {'variantId': 7098522, 'size': 'L/XXL - 36" - 40" (91-102cm)', 'sizeId': 7589, 'colour': 'Multi', 'colourCode': 'MU1', 'isPrimary': True, 'sizeOrder': 5}]
>>> data_json["variants"][0]['size']
'XXS/XS - W66-76cm'
>>> data_json["variants"][1]['size']
'S/M - W79-86cm'
```

Also below works for me in first case

```
>>> data = response.xpath('//script[contains(., "Pages/FullProduct")]/text()').re_first("view\('(\{.*\})',")
>>> data_cleaned = re.sub(r'[\\]+"', r'\"', data)
>>> data_cleaned = re.sub(r"[\\]+'", r"'", data_cleaned)
>>> data_json = json.loads(data_cleaned)
>>> data_json['brandName']
"Barney's Originals"
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. But my desired result is "Barney\'s Originals" and "L/XXL - 36\" - 40\ " (91-102cm)", because having only one "\" before any quote mark will not give me error when Ioading json file.

Comment: Why do you need a "\" before those? quotes

Comment: Wouldn't the "s after 36 and 40 confuse the json.loads?

Comment: My confusion comes from a json validator website: [link](https://jsonlint.com/), the double backslash before 36" and 40" wouldn't pass the json validator.
But I think your way works on both problems.
Does the below work the same as yours if it applys:
`response.xpath('//script[contains(.,"Pages/FullProduct")]/text()').re_first("view\('(\{.*\})',").replace("\\\\", "\\").replace("\\", "")`

Comment: There is a difference between a actual value and its memory representation in language. See this `>>> x = r"\\'"` and check `print(x)` and `x` in python REPL and you will see the difference. So if you see the value there are never `\\\\` present. Use print to see how many `\` exists

Comment: Wow, didn't know there are some many tricks in backslashes. Not sure I'll get it right next time. BLACK MAGIC!!!